# Scope of R.id values

Tags: android, resources

I'm looking for ways to reduce what I would call "id pollution" in my apps.  From what I can tell, `R.id` is global to the application, so in every Activity I usually create unique resource id values for elements, even if I have many of the same thing.  For example, if I have three Activity classes, each with a save and cancel button, I would define six unique id's for `R.id` like:

```
R.id.actOne_save
R.id.actOne_cancel
R.id.actTwo_save
R.id.actTwo_cancel
R.id.actThree_save
R.id.actThree_cancel
```

This seems unnecessary to me, as I should really only need two running on any Activity.  What are some of the practices that you all use when generating resource ids?  Do you reuse them between activites?  Is that OK if an id exists on two Activites (maybe one paused and one foreground) at the same time?  I'm afraid of weird behavior like a button click hitting too many listeners!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You're fine to use the same id across multiple elements, as long as they aren't in the same view.  So, all your save buttons could have the id of `btn_save` and as long as there aren't two of them in the same layout file, or attached layouts, then you're fine.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense given findViewById() is called from an Activity or View, instead of the Application. Cheers!

Comment: This is only 50% true at this time because you can see in the editor R.ids from foreign activities so you may think one of them is yours even if it does not exist in your activity.

Comment: @Martyn, what exactly do you mean by "in the same view"? If I have an activity layout that includes 2 fragment layouts, each fragment including an `id="@+id/button_ok", would this be a problem because they share the same parent view?

Comment: @bcorso if you do a findViewById on the parent then you're going to get in to trouble, if you do it one the root of each fragment, then you should be fine.  Just make sure that no element id is duplicated in the view hierarchy that you call findViewById on.

Answer (score 4):

I use:

R.id.activityName_type_action

where type may be *[btn|txtview|edittext|listview...]*

and action is something like *[save|del|accept|name|pin...]*

It's pretty verbose, but this way I can guess the identifier name from the activity without having to continuosly check the xml layout.

For example:

R.id.loginpin_btn_accept

R.id.loginpin_txtview_pin

Answer (score 1):

The other answers will work, but you could also make a save_button.xml in your layout folder, with `<Button>` as the root tag.  Then reference that guy's id in those places that you need it.  This means you only need to define one "save" button, and use it everywhere.