# What is the scope of android:id?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Scope of R.id values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719147/scope-of-r-id-values)

Could someone please clarify the scope of resource id's in Android?    Recently I was making a custom title bar which contained a RelativeLayout called "header".   I was invoking this title bar in the *onCreate()* handlers of each of my Activities thusly:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.title_bar);
```

One of my Activities had a TextView in its layout with the id of "header" and in that Activity's *onCreate()* I do a

```
TextView tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.header);
```

. . .  which blew up at runtime with ClassCastException, apparently because it thought I was trying to cast a RelativeLayout to a TextView.   Changing the name of the RelativeLayout in the title bar fixed it.

But I don't really understand this. Are Android resource id's global?     If so why wouldn't this collision be caught at build-time?

Note that this question has been asked before on SO: [Scope of R.id values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719147/scope-of-r-id-values)  . . .  Where the OP said "as far as I can tell" R.id's are global but my question is not a duplicate because neither of my questions is really addressed in that one.

Comment: Your question appears to be "Could someone please clarify the scope of resource id's in Android?" And the accepted answer for that question you linked seems to answer your question.

Comment: As I explained in my question, it's not a duplicate because neither of my questions is answered definitively.    The OP of the prior questions merely speculated that they are global, but no definitive answer was given, and the question of why it's not picked up at build time isn't even addressed.  (and I said all of this in my original question)

Comment: CommonsWare gives you a good answer to your second question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R.* values are global to their own type. So you can have a `R.string` and an `R.id` with the same name, but not two IDs with the same name. In your case, I feel that doing a build clean would have fixed your problem as well. For example, take a look at the R.java file contents:

```
    public static final class drawable {
    public static final int icon=0x7f020000;
    public static final int info=0x7f020001;
    public static final int menu=0x7f020002;
    public static final int splash1=0x7f020003;
}
public static final class id {
    public static final int ImageView02=0x7f070008;
    public static final int bestTimeTextView=0x7f070005;
    public static final int infoButton=0x7f070003;
    public static final int infoImageView=0x7f070000;
    public static final int levelSpinner=0x7f070002;
    public static final int menuImageView=0x7f070001;
    public static final int selectLevelTextView=0x7f070004;
    public static final int startButton=0x7f070006;
    public static final int timeTextView=0x7f070007;
}
public static final class layout {
    public static final int info=0x7f030000;
    public static final int menu=0x7f030001;
    public static final int splash=0x7f030002;
}
public static final class raw {
    public static final int down=0x7f040000;
    public static final int up=0x7f040001;
}
public static final class string {
    public static final int appname=0x7f060000;
    public static final int besttime=0x7f060002;
    public static final int help=0x7f060004;
    public static final int selectlevel=0x7f060001;
    public static final int start=0x7f060003;
}
```

Here I have the info name used in both drawable and layout parts, and the app functions perfectly. However, if I try adding two resources with the same ID, or two drawables with the same name, or two strings with the same name etc. it will not function properly.

Comment: I think Mark's answer is much better.

Comment: I agree with devmiles :P I'd rather lose 15 rep and have a better answer accepted.

Comment: "I think Mark's answer is much better"   Who's Mark?

Comment: CommonsWare's real name is Mark Murphy.

Comment: I checked your answer because it explained the naming scope more clearly and gave an example.   Basically after reading your answer I had the information I was looking for and your answer was first.    Also it had a less contentions attitude.     Also, you at least allowed for the possibility that this might have been catchable at build-time.

Answer (score 10):

> Are Android resource id's global?

They are "global" within an activity. The title bar is in the activity. The layout is in the activity. Widgets from both will be in the activity. Widgets with the same ID from both will be in the activity and will represent a point of conflict for `findViewById()` calls.

> If so why wouldn't this collision be caught at build-time?

First, why would it? How is the build system supposed to know that you are are going to take `res/layout/title_bar.xml` and `res/layout/whatever_the_heck_you_called_it.xml` and use them both in the same activity?

Second, there is nothing wrong with having duplicate IDs. Your job, as a developer, is to **call `findViewById()` on whatever will give you a unique result**. For example, you could have done:

```
TextView tv1 = (TextView)(findViewById(android.R.id.content).findViewById(R.id.header));
```

and kept the duplicate IDs. Going the route you did, of having distinct IDs, is a better choice here for maintainability. But there will be plenty of cases where you will intentionally have duplicate IDs, such as every `AdapterView` you ever implement (e.g., `ListView`), as their contents will tend to have duplicate IDs (e.g., each row in the `ListView` is stamped out from the same row layout resource).

Comment: If I do a findViewbyId with a non-existent resource it certainly catches that at build-time, so why wouldn't it catch a duplicate.  It has to resolve it to something so what determines what "something" it picks?

Comment: @user316117, also, read this article: [Layouts — ID](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#id). And according to source code of `findViewById` method, it returns first `View` in a tree with the given `id`.

Comment: @user316117: "so why wouldn't it catch a duplicate" -- because at build time it has no idea that it will actually be a duplicate, as I addressed in the answer. "also, read this article" -- I will quote here the relevant point from that "article": "An ID need not be unique throughout the entire tree, but it should be unique within the part of the tree you are searching (which may often be the entire tree, so it's best to be completely unique when possible)." In your case, you are searching the entire tree with an activity-level `findViewById()`.

Comment: ""so why wouldn't it catch a duplicate" -- because at build time it has no idea that it will actually be a duplicate, as I addressed in the answer"    Could you clarify this?  At build time it knows there are two resources with the ID of 'header' and it knows that 'header" is being referenced in the findViewById.  So what else does it need to recognize a conflict?   And if it just resolves 'header' to the first ID in R.id with that name then it also knows that it's a RelativeLayout and I'm trying to cast it to a TextView.   I think it has lots of info at build time to flag something.

Comment: @user316117: "So what else does it need to recognize a conflict?" -- there is no good way at build time to know definitively that both resources will be used in the same activity *and* the developer is not taking this into account in the way they access those widgets. "And if it just resolves 'header' to the first ID in R.id with that name then it also knows that it's a RelativeLayout and I'm trying to cast it to a TextView" -- the compiler knows that in terms of processing the results of `findViewById()`. The *implementation* of `findViewById()` has no idea what type you think the widget is.

Comment: "there is no good way at build time to know definitively that both resources will be used in the same activity"   They're not both being used - ONE resource is being referenced and there's more than resource by that name.  That's all it needs to know to flag an ambiguity.  The compiler or linker flag much more trivial things than that.

Comment: @user316117: "They're not both being used" -- according to your code, they are. "ONE resource is being reference" -- according to your code, TWO resources are being referenced (`R.layout.title` and whatever you are using with `setContentView()`). "That's all it needs to know to flag an ambiguity" -- no, it is not, because it is not a problem **until somebody tries using `findViewById()`**. And even then, it depends upon *what* gets `findViewById()` called upon it, since it could be based on all sorts of variables (e.g., contents of a Web service response).

Answer (score 0):

R is just a java class full of static integers. You can only have one value for R.id.header in your application.
It is perfectly fine to use the same id in your layouts but if you use identical id's in one layout you may run into the exact problem you've encountered.
In your case findViewById found your RelativeLayout first and returned it instead of a TextView. It's just a matter of order by which it searches for views.
You may still get around it by calling findViewById on your TextView's immediate parent for example.

Comment: "It is perfectly fine to use the same id in your layouts but if you use identical id's in one layout you may run into the exact problem you've encountered."     But it wasn't in one layout.   The Avtivity layout and the Title bar layout are two separate layouts.    And if R.id has Activity-wide scope then how would it ever be "perfectly fine to use the same id in your layouts"?

Comment: `in one layout` - I meant the same context, the thing which you're calling your findViewById on. And it is perfectly fine to use the same id, as I've said before. Your task is to call findViewById correctly.

Comment: You should have accepted Mark's answer.